# File exists - no such file

Tags: python-2.7, path, filenames

```
import os

myDir = "C:\\temp\\a"


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
  for file in files:
    # fname = os.path.join(root, file) # this works fine, yeah!
    fname = os.path.join(myDir, file)
    print ("%r" % (fname))
    src = os.path.isfile(fname)
    if src == False:
      print ("%r :Fail" % (fname))
    f = open(fname,"r")
    f.close()
```

I expected the two versions of fname to be the same, but I've found out the hard way that the above code doesn't work. I just want to know why, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`os.walk(myDir)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) walks all the subdirectories, recursively! When `walk` descends into a subdirectory, `root` will be that directory, while `myDir` is still the root directory the search started in.

Let's say you have a file `C:\temp\a\b\c\foo.txt`. When `os.walk` descends into `c`, `myDir` is still `C:\temp\a` and `root` is `C:\temp\a\b\c`. Then `os.path.join(root, file)` will yield `C:\temp\a\b\c\foo.txt`, while `os.path.join(myDir, file)` gives `C:\temp\a\foo.txt`.

You might want to rename your `myDir` variable to `root`, and `root` to `current`, respectively, so it's less confusing.

Comment: That explains that perfectly! Thank you.